# MaterialUI > Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'color')

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

Using material ui in my gatsby / react project, I wanted to create a theme, but I kept getting the error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'color')
    at component---src-pages-index-tsx.js:3230:104
    at transformedStyleArg (component---src-pages-index-tsxhead.js:8985:40)
    at handleInterpolation (commons.js:1179:24)
    at serializeStyles (commons.js:1304:15)
    at component---src-pages-index-tsxhead.js:700:91
    at commons.js:798:12
    at renderWithHooks (framework.js:17108:18)
    at updateForwardRef (framework.js:20024:20)
    at beginWork (framework.js:22434:16)
    at beginWork$1 (framework.js:28224:14)
```

*gatsby-browser.tsx*

```js
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme(
  {
    typography: {
      fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    }
  }
);

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{element}</ThemeProvider>;
};
```

Library versions:

*package.json*

```json
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.14.6",
    "@mui/material": "5.14.6",
    "@mui/material-next": "6.0.0-alpha.98",
    "gatsby": "5.12.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
```

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the issue, by extending the `defaultTheme` in `@mui/material-next`.

*gatsby-browser.tsx*

```js
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { defaultTheme } from "@mui/material-next";

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "quicksand,sans-serif",
  },
}, defaultTheme);

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{element}</ThemeProvider>;
};
```